# How to add Endpoints dynamically in Retrofit2.0

Tags: android

How to pass endpoints in annotations(ex:@GET("dynamic value"))dynamically.

We tried passing values as static and it was doing good but when i pass the values dynamically it is showing the below error

**Attribute value must be constant**.[image]

Comment: what would be its use case? It looks to me, if you want a *path*

Comment: Are you trying to change base url or just an endpoint path?

Comment: the above one is interface, so if someone is trying to reverse engineering my apk , all strings are visible as it is,so what i am doing here is , i am taking all these strings from other calsses and keeping here dynamically. i am talking all about endpoints only.

Comment: What sensitive information are you putting in URL that needs to be hidden? By the way - are you using SSL?

Comment: No, we are using Android NDK. we are hiding strings in .c files, so i am finally using these strings in API interface.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to do somthing like this:

```
@GET("users/list?country={country}")
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("country") String country);
```

where you give the country code when you call the function

Comment: thanks for your response,but actually i wanted to pass the whole string as dynamic value. example below:                                                               @GET(hhh)
Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("country") String country);

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Documented    
@Target(METHOD)    
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface GET {   
  //new
  int Endpoints () default 1;   (or use enum)    

  String value() default "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

```
.baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
.build();
```

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);